# Call class instance as function (JS/TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a logging class called Logger.

```
let log = new Logger(...);
```

Is it possible to specify a magic method in that class to be executed when the class instance is invoked as function? For example

```
log(...)
```

In php implementing the  __invoke() magic method of a class achieves the same thing.

Comment: You can return a function from your `Logger` constructor, but it will be an arbitrary function not an instance (not inheriting from `Logger.prototype`)

Answer (score 3):

```
function Logger() {
  return function log(arg1, arg2) {
    //@TODO: use the function's args
    // or the arguments property to
    // generate the log

    console.log(log.arguments);
  }
}
logger = new Logger();
logger('boom', 123, 'yolo');
```

This solution should to the trick you are looking for. How optimal it is or better ways of setting this up will probably be found in the comments below.

Comment: Please don't forget to include the drawbacks of this approach in your answer.

Comment: But this way Logger is not a class anymore, just a function.